# VueX store seems to have a keyword preventing "navigation.js" to be imported

Tags: vue.js, vuex, eslint, vuejs3

I have a store which had always worked. For some reason, I wanted to add a "navigation" module, as I did for all my other modules. Here is how I wrote it:

```
import navigation from './modules/navigation';
```

Nothing very particular here. But here is what vue-cli says:

```
  4:24  error  Missing file extension for "./modules/navigation"        import/extensions
  4:24  error  Unable to resolve path to module './modules/navigation'  import/no-unresolved
```

Well, I suppose `navigation` must but some sort of keyword, so I change my file to put the `.js` extension, and here is the message I get:

```
  4:24  error  Unexpected use of file extension "js" for "./modules/navigation.js"  import/extensions
```

Of course I have 2 solutions:

- disable the eslint rule
- change the name of the file

But I'd like to know why I receive these messages in the console. I didn't find anything in the documentation.
Thanks in advance!